# Booting Problem when resterting after directly shutting down

Tags: boot, grub2

I directly switched of my PC and when I started `GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-29` opens up.
Below that, inside a box, there are four options that are:

- *Ubuntu*
- Advanced options for *Ubuntu*
- Memory test (memtest86+)
- Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200

Below the menu there is written:

```
Use the up or down keys to select which entry is highlighted.
Press enter to boot the selected OS, 'e' to edit the commands before booting or 'c' for a command-line.`
```

There is a countdown of 30 seconds, if left idle the *Ubuntu* option gets executed (which was highlighted from default).

What can I do to start my PC?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? If "Ubuntu gets executed" I see no problem there. And if by "directly switched off" you mean the power button then the system wasn't properly shutdown so Grub is expected to show up in the next boot...

Answer (score 1):

## What you must know

**Don't worry, it is a normal behavior** and you computer should be fine.

You are already starting your *Ubuntu GNU/Linux* (the Operative System of your PC) correctly: there is no difference between waiting for the countdown or pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on the first entry.

If the system was not closed correctly, the boot process after selecting the Operative System will be a bit longer, because the filesystem **must** be checked for errors to maintain the system stable over time.

## Useful notions

The second entry (Advanced options) is for when you have serious boot problems or you want to start an older Ubuntu Linux [kernel](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computer_science%29).

<sup>**NOTE**: starting an older kernel *may* not allow the correct functionality of some applications and *will* expose you system to many security issues; I strongly suggest to always start the first menu entry, because it always uses the updated kernel.</sup>

The <kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>c</kbd> keys are only for advanced users and are intended to make temporary modifications to the system when the administrative users are locked out.

---

Welcome to the Ubuntu community, feel free to comment under here if you have more doubts.